# Laravel - Unknown column 'subscription_date' in 'group statement'

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to perform aggregate function and achieve a specific result that group by date, removing time from `datetime`.

Whenever I group by `created_at` the error will not be there but it will group by `datetime` and the result will not be accurate.

I have this query:

Your query seems correct but I think you forgot to retrieve the `as` keyword,

```
$revenuereports = DB::table('cloudsubscriptions as c')
 ->select(
       'c.service_name', 
        DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_users'), 
        DB::raw('SUM(c.amount) as total_amount'),
        DB::raw('DATE(c.created_at)as subscription_date') // you forgot as here
  ) 
 ->groupBy('subscription_date')                                                            
 ->orderByRaw('c.created_at DESC');

    $render=[];
    if(isset($request->start_date) && isset($request->end_date))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->whereBetween('created_at',[$request->start_date,$request->end_date]);
        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
        $render['end_date']=$request->end_date;
    }elseif(isset($request->start_date))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->where('created_at',$request->start_date);

        $render['start_date']=$request->start_date;
    }        
    if(isset($request->service_name))
    {
        $revenuereports=$revenuereports->where('service_name','like','%'.$request->service_name.'%');
        $render['service_name']=$request->service_name;
    }

    //dd($revenuedetails->toSql());
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->orderBy('created_at','DESC');
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->paginate(15);
    $revenuereports= $revenuereports->appends($render);
    $data['revenuereports'] = $revenuereports;

return view('report.revenueReport',$data);
```

I expect to have a result to filter by subscription_date (without time)

> "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'subscription_date' in 'group statement' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `cloudsubscriptions` as `c` where `created_at` between 2019-01-01 and 2019-06-30 group by `subscription_date`) "

How do I resolve it please?

Comment: You could just be explicit and group by `->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE('c.created_at')"));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the field in database?
Then you should forgot to add `as` just before `subscription_date`

```
$revenuereports = DB::table('cloudsubscriptions as c')
     ->select('c.service_name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_users'), DB::raw('SUM(c.amount) as total_amount'),DB::raw('DATE(c.created_at) as subscription_date'))
     ->groupBy('subscription_date')                                                            
     ->orderByRaw('c.created_at DESC')
     ->get();
```

BTW, i dont think you need a table alias for this query.

```
$revenuereports = DB::table('cloudsubscriptions')
     ->select('service_name', DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_users'), DB::raw('SUM(amount) as total_amount'),DB::raw('DATE(created_at) as subscription_date'))
     ->groupBy('subscription_date')                                                            
     ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
     ->get();
```

You can change your mysql `strict->false` and try.

You will find it on, `config/database.php > connections > strict (default it is true, just change it to false.)`

Comment: I added the table alias and the error is still there

Comment: Its may be because of your mysql driver strict is true.

Comment: I just checked to confirm and it is false.     'strict' => false,

Comment: The issue is still there. I added the full code. You can check

Comment: You just remove the table alias and try again. see my second code on the answer.

Comment: If you think you have to clear your config then run the code **php artisan config:cache**

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems correct but I think you forgot to retrieve the `as` keyword,

```
$revenuereports = DB::table('cloudsubscriptions as c')
     ->select(
           'c.service_name', 
            DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total_users'), 
            DB::raw('SUM(c.amount) as total_amount'),
            DB::raw('DATE(c.created_at)as subscription_date') // you forgot as here
      ) 
     ->groupBy('subscription_date')                                                            
     ->orderByRaw('c.created_at DESC')
     ->get();
```

Comment: I added the table alias and the error is still there